# Why doesn't the Jenkins CLI work on our Dev@Cloud instance?

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I've been unable to login to our Dev@Cloud instance using the Jenkins CLI WAR.  Every time that I try, I get the following message:

> You must authenticate to access this Jenkins.

My SSH keys are set in both our Jenkins instance and in GrandCentral.  I've tried executing the login command, but I end up with the following exception:

```
org.acegisecurity.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException: Not Found or Not Authorized
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.dacsecurity.auth.CloudBeesUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(CloudBeesUserDetailsService.java:60)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.dacsecurity.auth.CloudBeesUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(CloudBeesUserDetailsService.java:12)
    at hudson.security.SecurityRealm.loadUserByUsername(SecurityRealm.java:305)
    at hudson.cli.ClientAuthenticationCache.set(ClientAuthenticationCache.java:94)
    at hudson.cli.LoginCommand.run(LoginCommand.java:37)
    at hudson.cli.CLICommand.main(CLICommand.java:229)
    at hudson.cli.CliManagerImpl.main(CliManagerImpl.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.perform(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:275)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:256)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:215)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at hudson.cli.CliManagerImpl$1.call(CliManagerImpl.java:63)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$2.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:95)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any help on this one is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a case where the right ssh key isn't being used when you connect - it will look in ~/.ssh/id_rsa etc  - the same as the "ssh" command.

If you still can't work it out - please do open a ticket support@cloudbees.com as you may need to talk more specifically about your setup

You may need to put an entry in ~/.ssh/config like:

```
Host account.ci.cloudbees.net                                                                                                                                                                          
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

pointing to the private key you wish to use to identify (if you use the default one for your user you should be ok)

Comment: I generated a new .ssh key using the same ID as my cloudbees account.  It worked with that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s "https://[username].ci.cloudbees.com/" -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa help

If you havn't create ssh key follow this help guide till step3
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

your_email@example.com = can be any email, not necessarily the one you gave in cloudbee account login/setup